# Corona SDK, tableView: is there a way to force refresh- currently not showing new table entries

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to force a refresh/reload of the data on a tableView. I’m making an app where you tap a button to show a different group, in that new group you add a record to a sqlite database table and get returned to the original group with the tableView in. I need to reload this tableView to show the new value from the database.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- populate list from table:
myList:sync( itemData )
```

Comment: Corona did not age well, I would ndt dvelop new apps  with it :/

Comment: Thanks for the answere here Tom. Out of curiosity, what would you recommend for cross-platform application building? I've been on corona for a few months now, and I am starting to see the horizons of it's capabilities and becoming some what limited. Cheers